# Matching multiple string values in two columns in Alteryx

Tags: alteryx

Is it possible to compare strings in two different columns? I want to achieve something like this " If [field1] = [field2] ". My first thought is to use the filter tool but its a malformed statement.

Answer (score 1):

What is your goal? If your goal is to filter where [field1] = [field2] then yes, that's exactly what the [Filter](https://help.alteryx.com/20221/designer/filter-tool) tool does, (see link).

If you're trying to generate new data based on various conditions, you can use their [Formula Tool](https://help.alteryx.com/20221/designer/formula-tool), wherein you can utilize [Conditional Functions](https://help.alteryx.com/20221/designer/conditional-functions). Simple example: creating a new variable, say, `[NewVariableName]`, with an expression something like:

```
IF [field1] = [field2] THEN 
    "Hey they're equal!"
ELSE
    "Nope, not equal!"
ENDIF
```

Comment: Thank you. What im trying to do is to find the numerous values that are the same value in two different columns.

Comment: Ive tried what you suggested but im not getting any matches and I know there are matches. Im working with a large amount of data.

Comment: Can you send your table to both inputs of a join, and [field1] = [field2] as the join condition?

Comment: I did a filter with that input and i get "0" for true, which i know is not correct.

Comment: If you're trying to match field1 to field2 in the same row, maybe it misses. If you want field1 to match field2 in some other row, then you need to self join, as described in my previous comment: send your same data stream to both inputs of a join, and require field1 from the left or top input to match field2 from the right or bottom input.